# Rcpp_Modules: exposing class method with formal R arguments

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

[Rcpp-Modules vignette](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-modules.pdf) explains how to provide formal argument specification by passing a `Rcpp::List` after the function pointer for *free functions*. Is there any API to provide named and/or default arguments for *class methods*? Apparently, the same "function" technique does not apply here:

```
RCPP_MODULE(TestModule) {
  class_<TestClass>( "TestClass" )
  .constructor()
  .method( "method", &TestClass::method, 
            List::create(_["arg"])) //DOESN'T COMPILE
  ;
}
```

There are couple discussions on this topic ([here](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/2014-March/007324.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241687/how-to-export-rcpp-class-method-with-default-arguments)), but the solution offered in the first one boils down to using global functions and second involves extra layer of R wrapper functions to provide argument specification. Is there any neat method/workaround for this?

Comment: This may simply not be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I just played with it. The question makes not sense with Rcpp Modules:

- functions work by signature
- the argument is part of the signature, so you have to supply it anyway
- calling without an argument (to test the default argument) does not work as a `void` signature is assumed